# UFT not recognizes Delphi Objects?

Tags: delphi, object, testing, automation, qtp

I am facing an issue while recognizing **Delphi Objects** using **UFT**. 
I have even checked the **Delphi plugin** while recognizing the objects but every time it is showing a Window's type Object. Below is the screenshot for the same.
Please suggest some solution for this.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What is UFT? What is your question?

Comment: Unified Functional Testing (UFT) software, formerly known as HP QuickTest Professional (QTP), provides functional and regression test automation for software applications.

Comment: My Question is how to identify Delphi Application objects using UFT tool?

Comment: How did you code the target app? What components did you use? Apparently you didn't choose components that support accessibility or automation interfaces.

Comment: We don't have the source code of this application, client has provided this application for automation testing using UFT tool. This is the reason we would like to know the workaround for recognizing delphi objects using this tool.

Comment: There isn't going to be a workaround. The app isn't going to admit automation. Talk to the client about how they made that app and which components they use. You really need to understand how your automation tool works. It requires co-operation from the target app. It requires the target app to expose automation interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

To use Delphi add-in, you MUST have access to source code of application - to be able to **re-compile it with QTP integration** (and possibly with Delphi extensibility) units. You can't use Delphi add-in with your application out-of-the-box, without re-compiling it. Please, refer to Delphi add-in help in UFT.